# Some problem with listings and C++

Tags: listings

I have to insert a `C++` code in a `.tex` file but I want that is written with the text coloured like in the `C++` program. If I use `lstlisting` there is the `C++` program but in b/w.
Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need a coloring style -- the style depends on your own decisions of course

Answer (score 3):

The style is basically the some as given in the `listings` manual.

`listings` uses several `substyles` for keywords, strings, identifiers, comments, each one is basically called `....style` which can set to be 'anything' either in `\lstset` or in the optional argument of the `lstlisting` environment.

In addition, it's possible to define personal styles as a short-hand and use it with the `style=...` option. 
`\lstdefinestyle{style name}{key=value list}` defines such a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{language=C++,
  basicstyle=\small, % print whole listing small
  keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries\underbar,
  % underlined bold black keywords
  identifierstyle={\color{red}},%
  commentstyle=\color{brown}, % brown comments
  stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily, % typewriter type for strings, blue 
  showstringspaces=false
}


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  #include <iostream>
  // Hello World - Example
  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
  }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `stringstyle=\color{\blue}` should be `stringstyle=\color{blue}`

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, thank you. I've changed on disk and later on here, without copying. Stupid typo.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.84]{beramono}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{CPP}
 {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    identifierstyle=\color{red},
    commentstyle=\color{brown},
    stringstyle=\color{blue},
    tabsize=2,
}}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{CPP}
#include <iostream>
// Hello World - Example
int main( int argc, char **argv )
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
        return 0;
    }
\end{CPP}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Code stealer :-P